# Crashlytics for NDK just shows the method name in fabric logs

Tags: google-fabric

How can i get the line number??

I just get the method name in native crashes.

I have uploaded the symbols and followed the document for setting up NDK crashes in Crashlytics for my native code

Comment: Also, I have another app whose structure is different, It has two separate projects one which is java and another which is native code (C). Does crashlytics require both java and native code to be in the same project to report ndk crashes?

Comment: If you have another question, please post it separately.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here - did you upload the symbols post-crash or before causing the crash?

Comment: I have the exact same issue. I uploaded symbols before and after causing the crash. Same problem.

Comment: Uploaded symbols before crash but seems shcolf did it after too and sees the same issue